# Meta element for hand to hand combat?

Tags: magic, weapons

Swords have been around since the beginning of humanity and many other weapons. But if we could control the following elements: Fire, Wind, Water, Gravity and energy (Lighting).

**What would be the best element for a melee weapon and also what would be the weapon type?**

#### The magic system:

Weapons are made with a magical conductive steel. You wear a protective glove when holding a burning blade for example.

Magic respects some laws of physics but defies others. Magic works with line of sight and its range is limited by it.

The gravity magic is a bit odd. You can make your weapon superheavy or super light, throw a giant shuriken or arrow and turn it heavy at range.

The wind magic is odd too. You throw a slash and a wind wave at your target. Works better with large weapons.

The water magic: You can freeze water enough to rival metal in strength. Like, inside a hammer? Or around your sword?

Comment: maybe call it Inertia instead of Gravity...

Comment: "Super heavy" -- is that gravitational mass or inertial mass? In the real world they are identical to the best of man's knowledge, but is this the case with your magic?

Comment: What about fire and lightning? You left those out in your description of the magic system.

Answer (score 1):

## Use the Anti-Element

If you remove the base elements, what are you left with?

> A vacuum

You can have your mages create a vacuum in front of your weapon's leading edge to increase the speed and momentum.

Answer (score 1):

## Ranged

I think if you are using a ranged weapon as a bow, wind arrows could be pretty over powered. You could redirect them mid air, increase their speed, avoid obstacles... Gravity could be good too, but in fights between mages they aren't wearing too much armor. Also if you can hit with your arrow and then cast ice inside the opponent body that would hurt a lot.

## Melee

In melee I would pick lightning if the enemy wears armor, so if you hit his armor the lightning would shock him. Or water, if you can cast ice once the enemy is stabbed.
Fire sounds good but I guess it takes like 2 seconds to burn clothes and set the opponent on fire.